# Failed to activate swap /swapfile keeps happening

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap

So I've reinstalled Ubuntu several times over this. Whenever I turn the PC off after a few days lots of files go read only mode and then I get

```
systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile. 
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for swap.
```

I am brand new to Linux, I have 0 idea of what I am doing.  I'm only using it for better plot speeds for chia tbh so I need some help. I tried to remake the swapfile but since it's read only I can't.  I'm trying to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu for the simple fact it's just going to happen again and it takes days for my chia wallet to sync...  Any help would be appreciated, it just doesn't make sense why it is constantly happening after a couple days if I restart for any reason...

Here is a photo of what is displayed on my end when trying to boot into Ubuntu

[image: above errors and also Failed to start network name resolution, failed to start snap daemon]

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I really have no idea what I'm doing.. also nvme1n1p2 is not where Ubuntu or the boot files are if what it is displaying means it's trying to boot from that partition.

Comment: Is the entire disk going r/o, or just a few select files? Try doing `touch testing` and see if that works. Do you have a Ubuntu Live USB?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off the PC using the `poweroff` command the filesystem does a clean shutdown which writes the last bits to the harddisk. If you just cut the power, the next time Ubuntu will do a filesystem scan (fsck) and fix whatever it can. That mode may mount the whole file system be in read-only. A `reboot` will go back to the normal mode. If the files themselves are set to read-only you have to add the write flag like this `sudo chmod +w /swapfile`

The swapfile is an overflow space for memory, after a reboot the content isn't worth a thing, so you can remove the file and recreate it, I would use these commands, this one is 4Gb feel free to make it bigger

```
rm -rf /swapfile
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4 bs=1G
mkswap /swapfile
chmod 777 /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```